# flask-mongoengine AttributeError: 'BaseQuerySet' object has no attribute 'service_name'

Tags: flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

My Code:

**models.py**

```
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine, QuerySet
import datetime

db = MongoEngine()

class Service(db.Document):
    service_name = db.StringField(max_length=50, required=True)
    date_created = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    meta = {
        'ordering': ['-date_created'], 'strict' : False
    }

class Organisation(db.Document):
    org_name = db.StringField(max_length=50, required = True)
    service = db.ReferenceField(Service, reverse_delete_rule='CASCADE', required=True)
    date_created = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    meta = {
        'ordering': ['-date_created'], 'strict' : False
    }
```

**API(routes.py)**

```
@service.route('/services/<name>', methods=['GET'])

def get_one_service(name):
    s = Service.objects(service_name=name)  
    if s:
        output = {'service_name' : s.service_name}
    else:
        output = "No such name"
    return jsonify({'result' : output})
```

The `get_one_service()` method returns the above mentioned error. As per the documentation, this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `get_one_service` function, `s` is not a `Service` instance but a queryset ([this example](http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html#searching-our-posts-by-tag) from the documentation might make it clearer)

You can access a single instance of `Service` by doing something like:

```
try
    s = Service.objects.get(service_name=name) 
    output = {'service_name' : s.service_name}
except Service.DoesNotExist:
    output = 'no such name'
```

Though, since the `service_name` field is not unique in your model, you may get a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception if there's two documents with the same `service_name`.

Alternatively, you can see if `s` contains multiple `Service`s and act accordingly.